# how to write a trigger to assign a lead to account owner

Tags: apex, trigger, community

how to write a trigger that assignins the lead to account owner when the company field of lead matches with account name and  the lead address matches with account address
earlier i have used this code :

```
trigger update_lead_company on Lead (before insert, before update)

{
    list<string> com = new list<string>();

    for(lead ls: trigger.new)
        {
                 com.add(ls.company);
        }

    list<account> AccMatchLead= new list<account>([select id,name,ownerid,billingcity,billingstreet from account where name IN: com]);

       // map<string,id> IdOfAcc = new map<string,id>();
        map<string,id> OwnerOfAcc = new map<string,id>();   

        for(Account acc : AccMatchLead)
        {
          //  IdOfAcc.put(acc.name, acc.id);
            OwnerOfAcc.put(acc.name, acc.OwnerId);
        }


    for(lead ld : trigger.new)
    {
      //if(ld.street==AccMatchLead.billingstreet && ld.city==AccMatchLead.billingcity)
      {

          ld.ownerid=OwnerOfAcc.get(ld.company);
      }

    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't define the problem. You have explained what you have done.

Comment: i want a trigger that assigns a lead to account owner whenever company field of lead matches with the account name and also lead address matches with the account address

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: it is not assigning lead

Answer (score 2):

Your problem would appear to be with this portion of your code where you have the `if` statement commented out and don't include the `company name` as part of the `if` condition:

```
for(lead ld : trigger.new)
{
  //if(ld.street==AccMatchLead.billingstreet && ld.city==AccMatchLead.billingcity)
  {

      ld.ownerid=OwnerOfAcc.get(ld.company);
  }

}
```

This needs to be rewritten to look more like the following:

1st, `list<string> com = new list<string>();` needs to be changed to a set at the beginning of your trigger or else you need to use a map of type `<Id,string>`. Let's use a map.

```
map<id,string> comMap = new map<Id,string>();

for(lead ls: trigger.new)
    {
         comMap.put(ls.Id,ls.company);
    }
```

In your query, just use `comMap.values()` to replace `com`.

The next section needs additional maps, one for each part of the address OR you need to map the company name to the list of Accounts which is what we'll do here:

```
    for(Account acc : AccMatchLead)
    {
        accMap.put(acc.name, acc);
    }
```

Now, when we get to the section where everything comes together, you'll have what you need to test and equate using  the `ld.Id` to obtain `company` and other fields from `accMap` and `comMap`.

```
    for(lead ld : trigger.new)
    {
        if(accMap.keyset().contains(comMap.get(ld.Id)) &&  ld.street==accMap.get(comMap.get(ld.Id)).billingstreet 
           && ld.city==accMap.get(comMap.get(ld.Id)).billingcity){
              ld.ownerid=accMap.get(comMap.get(ld.Id)).OwnerId;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @crmprogdev,
I am bad at understanding maps but what I can understand is 
if(accMap.keyset().contains(comMap.get(ld.Id)) is checking 
account map (which contains key as account names) is checking if it contains lead id 

Shouldn't  it be 
if(accMap.keyset().contains(comMap.get(ld.company))?

Comment: In `comMap` contains the company name as the value and the key is the lead.Id. The accMap keyset in MY code is also company Name. I didn't use the acct.Id as a key in any of MY code.

Comment: Thank you, i get it now. so basically comMap.get(ld.Id) is returning the value of map.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it does. That part of the code is to test to see if lead company name is in the accMap keyset. If it's not, then there's no need to proceed.